# remove token repeatedly if line does not start with #

Tags: sed

I want to remove all commas from my text file unless a line starts with #

for example:

```
a, b, c
#a, b, c
```

should turn to:

```
a b c
#a, b, c
```

I don't mind double scan the file but I want to do that with sed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the below sed command,

```
$ sed '/^ *#/!s/,//g' file
a b c
#a, b, c
```

`^` asserts that we are at the start. So the above command will match the lines which starts with zero or more spaces and a `#` symbol. Then the following `!` makes the sed to inverse the selections ie, it forces the sed to do the replacement on the lines which are not matched. `s/,//g` replaces all the commas with an empty string .

Through awk,

```
$ awk '!/^ *#/{gsub(/,/,"")}1' file
a b c
#a, b, c
```

`!` at the start negates the patten. Likewise , it will do the replacement only on the lines which don't have `#` at the start.