# remove all comma characters from a line unless line starts with # using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove all commas from a line which does not start with #

for example:

```
a, b, c
#a, b, c
```

should turn into:

```
a b c
#a, b, c
```

and I want to do it in one line using regex

something like:

```
re.sub(r'(?!^\s*#) ...', "...", "a, b, c")
```

Comment: Regex is slow and (in this case) cumbersome, why do you insist on using it when it's easier to read and maintain code that applies the same functionality but doesn't involve using regex ?

Comment: What if the line contains spaces at the first?

Comment: just playing, no good reason

Comment: Same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058058/remove-token-repeatedly-if-line-does-not-start-with but with different tool.

Comment: @Ezra so you should accept vks's answer :)

Comment: @alfasin but that will capture and replace every lines which starts with `#`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj if you're saying that his solution is not good - then please explain. It looks fine to me.

Comment: @alfasin i'm talking about the processing time and the memory consumption. His regex will capture all the lines which starts with `#` symbol and replaces those lines with the same set of characters itself. But we really don't want to capture those lines. Where the other answers even won't touch the lines which starts with `#`. There is a hack for spaces at the beginning. See my comment on `@gl`'s answer.

Comment: @AvinashRaj the fact that regex is not the right tool here was already mentioned a few times and the OP insisted on regex for learning purpose which is why vks's answer should be the accepted answer. That said, your last comment is golden and should be placed under the accepted answer - not here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need conditional replacement here with regex.And python allows us to define a function as per our needs.See below.

```
import re
x="""a, b, c
  #a, b, c"""

def repl(m):
    if m.group(1):
        return m.group(1)
    else:
        return ""

print re.sub(r"^(#.*)$|,",repl,x,flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

You can do it this way using re.sub.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/60

This will capture line starting with `#` in a group and will capture rest of the `,` out of group.

Answer (score 4):

Non-regex approach: what if you combine [`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) with [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
print '\n'.join(line.replace(',', '') if not line.startswith('#') else line
                for line in data.splitlines())
```

Demo:

```
>>> data = """
... a, b, c
... #a, b, c
... """
>>> 
>>> print '\n'.join(line.replace(',', '') if not line.startswith('#') else line
...                 for line in data.splitlines())

a b c
#a, b, c
```

Answer (score 4):

Hard to do with a regex, but without it would be like

```
for line in lines:
    if not line.lstrip().startswith('#'):
        line = line.replace(',', '')
    # do whatever with line
```

Comment: change the if statement to `if not re.match(r'^ *#', line):` incase of spaces at the first. Because this is much more efficient that vks's..

Comment: @gl  oh, i forget that `lstrip` function . +1 from me.